# Pass Javascript/Ajax Data to form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I calcualte a price using jquery:

```
$('.label_1').click(function(){

    var total = 0;

    $('.option_1:checked').each(function(){

        total +=  parseInt($(this).val());
        });

        $('#total').html('€ ' + total);


    });
```

The price gets displayed in a DIV:

```
<div id="total"></div>
```

Now I need to pass the result to an HTML form field to submit and work with it.

Please any tipps how this could be done?

Thank you
Neil

Comment: Nice, for those who want to submit an altered request to lower the total price they need to pay... ;-)

Comment: Would you calculate using PHP ?

Comment: But I still can check on the next paymet step if total == TOTAL. If not {echo "Arrivederci";}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) of the input field to the total.

```
$("#theInputFieldThatShouldHaveTotalInIt").val(total);
```

Comment: Hi AJak, I know that this is the way - but to be honest: I have no clue how to do that.

Comment: Just `<input type="hidden" id="theInputFieldThatShouldHaveTotalInIt">`, @Neil. (But note it's not safe to rely on that value on the server!)

Comment: 100% agreed with @Arjan even though your doing this on the client side, your check should be done on the server side for pricing. If thats what your after. Client side validation is nice to have so you don't have users submitting invalid data, but that really should be its only purpose.

Comment: But I still can check on the next paymet step if total == TOTAL. If not {echo "Arrivederci";}  -  I have 3 different values and timeperiods. So checking for time period and Total == logic -> proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little code snnipet

```
<input type="text" id="tot">
<script>

$('.label_1').click(function(){

    var total = 0;

    $('.option_1:checked').each(function(){

        total +=  parseInt($(this).val());
        // in this secction send the total to the txt field
        $("#tot").val($total);
        });

        $('#total').html('€ ' + total);


    });
</script>
```

Comment: That's due to the `$` in `$total`. Also, the odd indenting in the question made lindosekai copy the curly brackets wrongly. The `each` should only update `total`; there is no need to update `$("#tot")` *within* that `each`.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a hidden input field for that. so what you can do is this.

since the the value of the you are trying to get is inside the div

```
!-- Hardcoded Value Example only -->
<div id="total">12</div>
```

And On your javascript   you can add this.

```
$(function(){
   $('.label_1').click(function(){

    var total = 0;

    $('.option_1:checked').each(function(){

        total +=  parseInt($(this).val());
        });

        $('#total').html('€ ' + total);


    });

     $('#myHiddenInputField').val($('#total').html());

})
```

once you have set the value of the `#myHiddenInputField` you can now submit the form either programmatically or just by clicking a submit button on form (if the form is visible)

Comment: It works when I use the harcoded exampe- but not with the jquery generated data.

Answer (score -1):

To do such kind of things HIDDEN input should be used.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_hidden.asp